# Avoiding Wither Projectiles

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am currently fighting the wither and am annoyed that I always have the wither affect on me. I tried to dodge the blasts, but I am in the jungle and it's almost impossible to escape. So, is there a way to somehow dodge the projectiles or are you shot no matter where you run and your speed?

Comment: Nope, fighting in Minecraft is all about clicking as fast as you can.

Comment: You should have spawned it close to bedrock in a double obsidian walled room. It would have killed itself in no time.

Comment: ♫ You gotta run through the jungle ♪ …and find a clearer place to lure and fight it.

Comment: @jeffreylin_ as least durring the snapshot, they could break obsidian.

Comment: @tkbx that's why I said doubled walled and near bedrock.

Comment: Milk cancels out all potion effects, including Wither, also, if you hate it that much, just put it on Easy, no wither effect!

Comment: If you brought a lot of TNT with you, then just place it and blow up the trees and get out of the jungle and kill the wither for the wither star!

Answer (score 1):

I should go hide in a strip mine(1 by 2) and slowly let the wither break through it, while you kill it.

Watch a Youtuber try it:

Comment: Sorry, but the wither would just shoot me with skulls and kill me! And by the way, that minecrafter is Antvenom. Nice try trying to impress me, but nothing.

Comment: @DanielPalamarchuk Have you watched the video? It's quite an effective technique, since the skulls impact on the walls and don't reach you. It doesn't actually help your jungle situation, of course…